# Adding invitations from email in Thunderbird (v. 91) on Mac Calendar.app

Tags: macos, thunderbird, calendar.app

I'm a macOS user. When I use Thunderbird (91.5.0) and when I get an email with the invitation to a calendar event, it allows me to save it in the Thunderbird calendar. As I use the default Mac Calendar.app, I want all invites to be saved in that app, NOT in Thunderbird calendar.

At this moment, I forward the message with the invitation and from the new message - I double click on the attachment then select to open it and choose the Calendar.app.
Is there a way of removing the Thunderbird calendar completely? So the invitation comes as a file, not as the event for the Thunderbird calendar? I heard that previous versions of Thunderbird did not have a built-in calendar. The latest one does have.

Thanks for help

P.S. For those, who will advise me to use the native Apple's Mail.app - I use it, but for private purposes, that's why I installed another client for work purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Using Thunderbird 102.3.3 I was able to save invites with Calendar.app like this:

- click invite.ics attachment to open it (or right-click + open)
- opening dialog comes up, choose "Open with CalendarFileHandler", see screenshot

[image: opening invite.ics dialog]